# looping google map and display each location in a different map, VUE JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to loop google map and display each location in different map. But in my way I couldn't loop the map. and the only location that displays is last item's address in the array.

First I loop the `api.data` in the parent and send it to child...

```
<div class="" v-for="item in api">
    <app-list :item="item" v-on:updateList="api = $event" />
</div>
```

then in child, I set the google map in `method`.

```
mounted() {
    this.initMap();
},
initMap: function(){
    var lat = parseFloat(this.item.lat);
    var lng = parseFloat(this.item.lng);

    var map = new google.maps.Map(this.$refs.mapContainer), {
        zoom: 14,
        center: {lat:lat, lng:lng}
    });

    this.markers = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {lat:lat, lng:lng},
        map: map,
    });
},
```

and put the map canvas in the loop in child component.

```
<transition  name="mapSlide">
     <div id="mapContent" v-show="openBox">
         <div id="listMaps" ref="mapContainer"></div>
     </div>
</transition>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your components are drawing to the same DOM element, the one with ID "listMaps", so they overwrite each other:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("listMaps"), {...}
```

Instead you need each component to draw into its own template.  You could use different IDs for each one and pass it to google  maps that way, but it would be simpler to use a component $ref:

```
 <div id="mapContent" v-show="openBox">
      <div ref="mapContainer></div>
 </div>
```

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(this.$refs.mapContainer), {...}
```

This way each component passes its own DOM element on to google maps, instead of all of them fighting over the same element.